# Using Pandas with Idle

Tags: python, pandas, spyder, python-idle

I wrote code in spyder which does not work in python (3.6) IDLE.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', usecols = ['A','B'])
print(df)
```

This should print the DF but it just prints an empty frame. I have installed Pandas and xlrd. How do I make this work in IDLE?

Edit:

This is the excel table.

[image: Excel Table]

Edit2: This is the output.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

When I try to write code with the DF errors occur.

Code Example:

```
keylist = []
list1, list2 = df['A'].tolist(), df['B'].tolist()

for i in zip(list1, list2):
    val = map(str, i)
    keylist.append('/'.join(val))

print(keylist)
```

> KeyError: 'A'

I think python tries to do something with an empty DF. But How can I make it read the excel file properly?

Comment: Can u post your sample data from excel file?

Comment: Any errors that you get ?

Comment: You may not have installed `pandas`, so I would say that either install it or use `Anaconda` that will include all required libraries

Comment: I have installed pandas with pip and I used it before hm..., I am downloading Anaconda right now

Comment: @Abhishakegupta , usecols parameters are wrong. please see below answer\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `usecols` need to be String if using column names:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', usecols = 'A,B')
```

I have tested this and as mentioned above is the case.

From Documentation :

> usecols : int or list, default None
>
> If None then parse all columns, If int then indicates last column to
>   be parsed If list of ints then indicates list of column numbers to be
>   parsed If string then indicates comma separated list of Excel column
>   letters and column ranges (e.g. “A:E” or “A,C,E:F”). Ranges are
>   inclusive of both sides.

Comment: That helped! Thanks! This is strange because in Spyder/Anaconda it worked in [] but in IDLE it doesnt.

Comment: Glad, it helped.